# Загрузка части json

Tags: ajax, json

В json храню информацию о картинках: url, аннотации, дату публикации, функциональные параметры и т. д.
Я гуглил, также смотрел тут, но так не понял, как через ajax загрузить часть json.
Хочу загрузить 20 объектов, вывести их на страницу, закрыть запрос. При достижении скролла к концу страницы, опять 20 объектов загрузить с того же файла json, вывести, и так далее до конца.
Дело также в том, что серверная часть отсутствует. Есть просто голый json, который лежит в папке на сервере.
Вообще возможно такое? И каким образом тогда, приведите, пожалуйста, код или пару функций для работы с этим.  Или лучше поискать другие пути для такого?

Comment: конечно, возможно. Запрос должен содержать номер страницы данных, а сервер отвечающий на запрос, сформирует набор объектов-записей для этой страницы и вернет их в JSON-формате.

Comment: @Igor, серверная часть отсутствует, забыл сказать. Добавил пару слов об этом к вопросу. Сайт статический.

Comment: Тогда - никак. Грузите весь файл сразу и показывайте частями.

Comment: @Igor, ага, спасибо, так и буду делать) Ну если бы серверная часть была, вопроса бы не было, конечно же.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что этого будет достаточно. Получение данных с сервера может занимать гораздо меньше времени, чем добавление элементов в DOM.

Comment: Еще вариант - иметь на сервере много JSON файлов, с названиями, отражающими номера кусков данных.

Comment: @Igor, ну разбивать на json-парты - нормальный вариант... Но я ни разу не работал с json, вот впервые буду учиться. Поэтому этот вариант может сработать, но тогда скажи, как вообще составлять json-данные? Самому вручную забивать вместе со всеми скобочками и кавычками, или есть какие-то сервисы? Или проги для этого? Можно, конечно, и самому написать на плюсах, но наверняка уже есть решения?

Comment: попробуйте поискать: "C# write objects in JSON format" или "C++ write objects in JSON format" или "PHP write objects in JSON format"

Comment: @Igor да я не об этом. И в самом js есть функции для парсинга и сериализации данных.  Я спрашиваю про более удобный способ "забивать" новые данные в json, а не как я думаю: открывать редактор, делать разметку, заносить ключ-значение, ставить кавычки, сохранять и грузить на сервер. Не знаешь ли готовых решений для такого добавления данных к json?